# Pivot query assistance

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Job Batch id   Company Outlet Id   Clearance required   Hanky required 
1              10                  T                    T
```

Now I want the the following

```
Job Batch id   Company Outlet ID    Reason    
1              10                   Clearance Required , Hanky Required
```

My brain has frozen so was needing assistance ?

How to construct this unpivot query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go -- just combine your columns like such.  I'm using STUFF to remove the beginning comma:

```
select JobBatchId, 
  CompanyOutletId,
  STUFF(
    ISNULL(CASE WHEN ClearanceRequired = 'T' THEN ',Clearance Required' END, '')  +
    ISNULL(CASE WHEN HankyRequired = 'T' THEN ',Hanky Required' END, '') 
    , 1, 1, '') Reasons
from YourTable
```

And the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/704bd/1).

Answer (score 1):

I'd advise against putting multiple values within a single column (`Reason`) in your Sql query, and instead leave that up to your presentation layer if that's how you want to see the data...

But here's how you can do it in Sql:

```
SELECT
    [Job Batch Id],
    [Company Outlet Id],
    CASE 
        WHEN [Clearance Required] = 'T' 
        THEN 'Clearance Required' 
        ELSE '' END +
    -- Determine if the comma is needed or not...
    CASE 
        WHEN [Clearance Required] = 'T' 
            AND [Hanky Required] = 'T' 
        THEN ' , ' 
        ELSE '' END +
    CASE
        WHEN [Hanky Required] = 'T' 
        THEN 'Hanky Required' 
        ELSE '' END AS Reason
FROM YourTable
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
select [Job Batch id], [Company Outlet Id],
       case [Clearance required]
            when 'T' then 'Clearance Required' + 
                case [Hanky required] when 'T' then ' , ' else '' end
       else ''
       end + case [Hanky required] when 'T' then 'Hanky Required' else '' end as [Reason]
from theTable
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UNPIVOT`, `CROSS APPLY` and `FOR XML PATH` to get the result:

```
;with cte as
(
  select [Job Batch id], [Company Outlet Id],
    col, value
  from yourtable
  unpivot
  (
    value
    for col in ([Clearance required], [Hanky required])
  ) unpiv
)
select distinct t1.[Job Batch id], 
  t1.[Company Outlet Id],
  left(s.reason, len(s.reason)-1) reason
from cte t1
cross apply 
(
  select t2.col + ', '
  FROM cte t2
  where t1.[Job Batch id] = t2.[Job Batch id]
    and t1.[Company Outlet Id] = t2.[Company Outlet Id]
  FOR XML PATH('')
) s (reason)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/46100/13)

Or you can use `UNPIVOT`, `STUFF` and `FOR XML PATH`:

```
;with cte as
(
  select [Job Batch id], [Company Outlet Id],
    col, value
  from yourtable
  unpivot
  (
    value
    for col in ([Clearance required], [Hanky required])
  ) unpiv
)
select distinct t1.[Job Batch id], 
  t1.[Company Outlet Id],
  STUFF(
         (SELECT ', ' + col
          FROM cte t2
          where t1.[Job Batch id] = t2.[Job Batch id]
            and t1.[Company Outlet Id] = t2.[Company Outlet Id]
          FOR XML PATH (''))
          , 1, 1, '')  AS Reason
from cte t1
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/46100/16)